# How to get latest sudoers and sshd_config after Ubuntu update?

Tags: updates, sudo, openssh

Just updated to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. During the update it warned me that I modified the sudoers and the sshd_config files (which I did). For the sudoers file, no merge option was provided and for the sshd_config file there was, but I first selected the option that shows the differences only. While trying to escape that prompt, I skipped out of the merge option as well. How can I still incorporate the newest additions to these files, after the update has finished? Thank you!

Comment: Then use `vimdiff` or whatever your preferred `diff` tool is to compare and merge changes

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's it.